# Is it possible to develop on ios, with Windows?

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform

I've already written a pretty good Android app in Kotlin, and I'd like to rewrite it into a cross-platform look now. But the question arises that I do not have Mac devices, but I have an Iphone phone, is it possible to somehow start programming for iOS using for example Flutter? and instead of using an emulator, use your phone?

I mean not just the flutter but the other cases as well

Comment: here is your answer most probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You will continuously need a MacOSX atmosphere. you may check out hosted MacOSX solutions or connecting to a virtual session however eventually you may want a Mac. Having aforesaid that, you'll be able to truly produce code inside any editor of your alternative. However, you're not progressing to be able to simply correct the code, and you may want a MacOSX atmosphere to submit any project to the App Store.

Note that once selecting a machine you ought to get one that may support the newest OSX version if potential.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can *develop* your flutter app in every platform you want, but for testing and deploying you will need a MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can develop.If you are using Windows you need to setup Virtual Machine and MacOS and you can develop for IOS