# Using VirtualBox for flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm just starting out to learn the Flutter and I found out I can't build, test, emulate... iOS app from windows laptop.

Can I use mac OS image with virtual box to target iOS device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter)