# Cannot use my iphone as adb in vscode on my windows machine

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a windows pc and having vs code installed, but I have a IOS phone iPhone 11

I am a flutter developer(App developer) I want to test my created app on my iPhone, My laptop has a type 3.0 cable I used to connect with my iPhone

My iPhone is connected to my laptop using wire, i can control my ios from windows explorer but i cannot see connected device available in my vscode

In explorer

[image]

**[image: strong text]**

But only 3 devices is connected in vscode

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an app on an iPhone in windows OS. you have to use Mac OS to run or test the IOS app. Apple limited environment of IOS and iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't run flutter apps from a Windows environment to ios the only way is you have a Mac device.

you can check the following question and see the suggestions there it might help you understand why it's not possible to this.
[Developing for iOS device in Windows environment with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter#:%7E:text=unfortunately%20flutter%20not%20capable%20for,usb%20without%20needing%20a%20macos.)