# IOS in android studio?

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart, cross-platform

I have a ready-made project in android studio and I wondered if I could build the same application for ios system?[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0qJM.png) If this is not possible, please advise on the best way to do this and what applications should be used for this.

I tried to search for help on the Internet, but could not find a suitable answer. I expect to create a project supported on two platforms

Comment: In windows you cannot build or run for iOS and MacOs. You need MacOs to build for iOS.

Comment: it's a pity, did I understand correctly, in order to create projects for ios, you also need to buy a macubk 

Comment: No, actually you can create iOS app in windows as well but to test the app or build for iOS you need Macbook

Answer (score 1):

To use your Flutter App as an iOS Application, you need a macOS System. On older Versions of macOS you could create a virtual system on your Windows pc to run macOS, but with the current versions it is not possible.

You can read more about this topic on the [apple Developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/54124).
And there is another interesting discussion on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter).

If you somehow manage it to build the app for iOS on your Windows Computer, you still need Xcode to sign and upload your app to the App Store.

**To make it short, you need a macOS system to create an iOS app.**
But this does not mean that your Flutter Project isn't able to build an iOS App. To initiate this process, it's just crucial to use a mac

If you don't know anyone who could help you out with a mac you could [rent one in the cloud](https://www.macincloud.com).

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ