# Error when building iOS Flutter app using CodeMagic on Windows: Error (Xcode): F.../XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am building a Flutter iOS app using [code magic](https://blog.codemagic.io/how-to-build-and-distribute-ios-apps-without-mac-with-flutter-codemagic/) virtual machine (as on windows), as suggested by an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006906/developing-for-ios-device-in-windows-environment-with-flutter). But I am getting this error message from CodeMagic when building.

One suggestion I have found is to amend the podfile, but I don't have/ can't create a podfile as on windows.

Is there any way to fix this error?

```
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode-14.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a
```

Comment: Hey there!

I'd suggest you try Appollo (https://github.com/Appollo-CLI/Appollo).

It's a python CLI tool that helps you configure your builds, test and publish your app on the app store!

Comment: @JulienP95 would be good if you acknowledge your involvement in the Appollo product when recommending it to people here.

Comment: Hello @Maks, yes, I am involved in the project. Did you give it a try yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Flutter plugins will need to configure their build on iOS with specific native libs via cocoapods and then need this committed into your git repo. You can do this by using the [Codemagic feature which allows remote access via SSH or VNC to the Mac mini VM your build is running on](https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/) which then will allow you to run the required cocoapods command and then commit the generated files and push that back to your remote git repo (eg. GitHub, GitLab, etc)

Also you can ask for help with this on Codemagics GitHub discussions, where, if you provide the build ID for your workflow that had that error, Codemagic support staff can then look up the detailed error logs for your workflow to help them assist you in fixing the issue.