# How to get Flutter Application running on real ios device with Windows?

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

Is there a way to get a Flutter Application running on own ios device with Windows and without paying money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is **not possible** to run an iOS simulator on Windows.

The reason for this is [the following](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) (highlighting is mine):

> Simulator allows you to rapidly prototype and test builds of your app during the development process. Installed *as part of the **Xcode tools*** [...]

This means that iOS simulator come only with **Xcode**. And [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) is *only available on **MacOS***.
This means that you will either need to run MacOS yourself or use a service that runs your app on MacOS for you.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573/6509751

---

For *Flutter* this means that you will have to test your code on Android, Desktop, or Web locally. You can still run an iOS simulator in your CI or do something similar to what was described in the answer linked above.