# XCode alternative workflow for Windows

Tags: ios, windows, xcode, visual-studio-code

I have recently got myself an Asus Rog strix 16 for pretty much half of the retail price. Even though I don't play games, I couldn't resist the specs for that price. With 64gb RAM, intel i9 13980hx rtx4070. Previously, I was using a Macbook Pro. Now the issues is that I have some iOS projects and looking for a recommendation on developing MacOS/iOS apps on Windows. For most of my other projects I use VSCode or neovim, I also have Visual Studio 2022 but never really used it. I need a workflow that will allow me to build and run an iPhone simulator with the app just like in XCode.

So far, I have tried running MacOS in VMWare but for some reason the GUI is extremely laggy, most likely due to not being able to utilize the GPU as the max vmram limit is 128mb.

If you are developing Apple apps on Windows the please let me know your workflow. I only need a simple solution that will help me build the app and run a simulator with it, I'm not looking for any complex functionalities or features. Before you ask, why I don't just use the MacBook, I'm planning to give it away so I won't be able to use it anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can do this [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) if you are developing in Xamarin.iOS, but if you are writing in Swift or similar you are probably going to want a Mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I develop for iPhone using a Windows development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358/how-can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-a-windows-development-machine)

Answer (score -2):

if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {

```
    UIView *statusBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame];

    if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

        statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:statusBar];



} else {
    UIView *statusBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame];

    if ([statusBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {

        statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Please don't post code-only answers. A good answer explains the problem and how it resolves the issue. 2. What does this code have to do with the question? The question is asking how to develop iOS app using MS Windows on a PC.